# Can I ask for app recommendation on the main site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should I ask for Android app recommendation on main site or on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: See: [Clearly-written app recommendation questions are borderline on-topic?](/q/2404/16575) and [Can we get software recomendations added to on topic discussions?](/q/2017/16575) – the answer is NO. Asking for software is on-topic on SR – but please check [their quality rules](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) before posting there.

Answer (score 5):

No, app recommendations are off-topic for us, just because they don't work very well with the SE format, which favours questions with an objectively correct answer. That said, if you have a specific problem to solve, and the answer might be one of:

- App X can solve your problem
- You need to install a custom ROM to do that
- There isn't an app, but if you do A in app X, and then B in app Y, then it'll solve your problem

and you'd be happy with any of those answers, then your question isn't an app recommendation: it's a problem-solving question. In that case, it's fine (unless it's off-topic for a different reason, such as you're trying to use an iPhone, not Android).

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) has its own guidance, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), explaining what makes a question suitable for that site.

> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> - A **purpose** — a task to accomplish, a user story
> - Some **objective requirements** — a minimum set of features

If your question has those, and you're definitely looking for an app, then your question is probably a better fit for that site.

If you don't have a purpose or objective requirements - for example, your question is "Which music player should I use?" - then your question probably isn't a good fit for any SE site, because of the aforementioned limitations of the format. In that case, you should probably ask on a discussion forum or on Reddit, where questions can be completely subjective and have many answers.